# Postfix setup for LAN only

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have Ubuntu on which I installed Postfix.
Postfix packet is up and running.
I'm trying to make a simple e-mail system to work between a few LAN computers.
Basically, I need to have some outlook clients able to exchange e-mails between them. I don't mind using the server IP address in outlook.

What is the easiest way to setup a LAN-only e-mail system using postfix ?

I did read some tutorials but they are very confusing for me because I don't have experience with linux or e-mails.

Other probably important notes:
So far in the main.cf I have added as **mydomain internal.tmp** and the local IPs to the networks (although they are also public, which is technically absurd and kind of wrong, but this is the current configuration of my friends network).

So practically, next I want to add some users like user1@internal.tmp, user2@internal.tmp that I want to configure in outlook clients so they can mail between them. How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance for any helpful info.

Answer (score 3):

This question is likely to be too broad for ServerFault, but I'll have a go at pointing you in the right direction.

Postfix is an MTA (**M**ail **T**ransfer **A**gent) and as such will only transport email between systems - for example, receiving email from either clients and forwarding to destination servers, or receiving email intended for other servers and forwarding it on - the latter is called *relaying*.

What you need is a mail server such as [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/), which will store your mail and make it available to your clients over IMAP (or POP if you want to be *really* archaic).

As you've hinted, you will need to configure Dovecot (or your chosen mailserver) to authenticate users. Dovecot itself can integrate with a wide range of user authentication databases (for example: local (i.e. system) users, virtual users defined in files, MySQL, LDAP).

Postfix can be configured to use SASL and authenticate users using Dovecot - even if your server isn't publicly available I would still do this out of habit and best practice.

Comment: Thank you, I will install Dovecot and come back with questions if there are any unknowns.

Comment: It did not work to install Dovecot directly on Ubuntu, but it seems to be ok if I install the sub-modules (dovecot-sieve,managesieved  , mysql, imapd, pop3d, common). Also initctl cannot start dovecot (unknown job) so ran it directly. Further testing now.

Comment: I did further testing. On ubuntu, I got to the point of being unable to send anything from outlook. It can't connect to outgoing server. On CentOS, I tired a configuration with local only name 'testname4' but I'm unable to send test e-mails with mailx, I get bounced (unable to look up host testname4.localdomain: Name or service not known). I can't figure out whats wrong with the host.

Comment: I use postfix and I can access my mail using IMAP over TLS. So I'm not too sure why you'd bring Dovecot in the mix?! postfix is perfectly capable of saving emails in a user's account. However, the IMAP/TLS scheme does not work with Outlook. That being said, for internal use, you can drop the TLS part and it works just fine with Outlook.